# can't get values form html select to php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

i can't get values from the HTML select menu to js and from there to sql... the problem is in the JS code - it's probably caused by bad syntax... or misplace values.....

here is the varibles from the JS file

```
var select = $('select.select').val();
```

here is the varibles from the PHP file

```
$select = filter_var($_POST['select.value'],FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
```

here is the SELECT menu from the HTML file

```
 <select name ="select" class="select">

<option disabled selected id="none"> -- select an option -- </option>
<option value="roy">roy</option>
```

here is the FULL code , the PHP code is in the Console area - because i didn't manage to upload the code correctly...

[code](http://jsbin.com/yufita/1/edit?html,js,console,output)
Thanks Ahead !

Comment: Can you post your whole form? Are you remembering to use the `<form>` tags?

Comment: Sure - here is the complete code - http://jsbin.com/yufita/1/edit?html,js,console,output

Answer (score 1):

`$_POST` uses `name="select"`, so:

```
$select = filter_var($_POST['select'],FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
```

Comment: You Probably right - but the JS code doesn't move to the PHP file... incase the JS is OK.....

Comment: here is the PHP varibles :$name = filter_var($_POST['name'],FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$email = filter_var($_POST['email'],FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
$email = filter_var($email,FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
$phone = filter_var($_POST['phone'],FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$select = filter_var($_POST['select'],FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

Comment: try to remove `#` from `<form action="#"`

Comment: dap.tci - Yes Ajax to post the data in  PHP

Comment: The problem is only in the JS code (Jquery), the select var is causing the code to stop...

Comment: It's hard to debug in jsbin. When code stops, is there an error message?

Comment: well no - since there is a "IF ELSE" statment - so i put an alert if the statment does not sustains.... else {
        alert('123'); and it does't according to the ELSE...